# Android / Java : GC_CONCURENT when creating many String's

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I'm blocking with a problem from a few days. I've found some similar posts but still didn't understanding the problem of my code.

In fact, I'm reading a file (18,4Kbytes) which is containing SQL queries. So the only thing I want to do is read the file and execute the queries.

I've no problem reading the file, the problem occurs when after having executed all the queries (if I don't execute it, it works but it's not the deal!)

So here's my code (between try / catch for IO Exception):

```
InputStream in = ctx.getAssets().open("file.sql");
ByteArrayBuffer queryBuff = new ByteArrayBuffer(in.available());
String query = null;
int curent;

while (-1 != (curent = in.read())) {
    queryBuff.append((char) curent);

    if (((char) curent) == ';') {
        query = new String(queryBuff.toByteArray());
        db.execSQL(query);
        queryBuff.clear();
        query = null;
    }
}
in.close();
queryBuff.clear();
```

And my GC_CONCURENT occurs when there is "new String" in the loop, after the end of the loop.

Thanks !

EDIT :
I'm a little annoyed, because my memory-leak didn't occurs in this part of code but in a part of code executed laterly (don't know what for now) but my problem wasn't a problem, app worked properly in fact...
Sorry !

Comment: You should read my blogpost about String objects.
[Read here](http://ernelljava.blogspot.se/2012/04/do-not-create-objects.html)

Comment: Thanks ernell but I tried with a StringBuilder appending my char's but it always turned to the same problem.
I did sb.append and after sb.toString for executing the sentence, and then sb.delete(0, sb.length()) but stills the same problem.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: What @Voo said, do you have a performance problem? You are allocating memory and throwing it away. Usually not a problem

Comment: Maybe you should filter out new lines by the way. And if there are new lines, just change to `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ctx.getAssets().open("file.sql")));`  And use `readLine` instead ?

Comment: As I said, the problem occurs by the String creation, we I comment it, the application is working properly (but not like I wanted).
So after the loop, GC is walking on my unreferenced vars but it causes app crash :
First :
`GC_CONCURRENT freed 171K, 45% free 3245K/5831K, external 716K/1038K, paused 6ms+5ms`
...
Lastly : `Out of memory on a 24-byte allocation.`
So : `E/AndroidRuntime(494): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]`

Comment: So this has absolutely nothing to do with GC whatsoever, but you're simply running out of memory. Apart from the extremely confused string creation, you're not leaking any memory in there, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Voo and sorry for my question. I edited the main question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I tried that sb.delete(0,sb.length()); It is slower than sb.setLength(0);

Comment: Are the queries of the same type??? If so, you should use PreparedStatement, not do quieries one by one. Its like 10000 times faster. Just build your PS in the loop and execute it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @ernell it's very use ful, I didn't think about preparing the queries but it's naturally faster :)